# Why is $P(A_i \cap A_j)= [\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)+P(A_i \cap A_j \cap (\cup_k A_k)^c)]$

Tags: probability

I'm reading the proof on that the probabilities in the Bonferroni's inequality are decreasing, i.e. if we let $P_2=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n} P(A_i \cap A_j),\; P_3=\sum_{1\le i<j<k\le n}P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k), \dots$, then we have $P_2\ge P_3.$

The argument given in the proof requires the following identity:
$$\begin{align}
P_2 & = \sum_{1\le i<j\le n}P(A_i \cap A_j) =\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n P(A_i \cap A_j) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \Bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)+P(A_i \cap A_j \cap (\cup_k A_k)^c)\Bigg].
\end{align}$$

However, I can't figure out how to get the last equality, that is how $P(A_i \cap A_j)= \Bigg[\sum_{k=1}^n P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)+P(A_i \cap A_j \cap (\cup_k A_k)^c)\Bigg]$.

Below is excerpt from the text Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone help me understand this.

Comment: The formula $$P(B)=P(B\cap A^c)+\sum_{k=1}^nP(A\cap A_k)$$ with $$A=\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k$$ can only hold if the sets $A_k$ are disjoint. One can only suspect some serious typos in your question...

Comment: @Did Yes I think there's a typo from the proof (it's from Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference) but I can't think of how to modify this, since the proof requires a sum of this form. I've posted the excerpt.

Comment: @Did But if we want to express $P(A_i \cap A_j)$ as the sum of $P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)$ and some additional terms, don't we also need to subtract some probabilities from it as well? So how can we guarantee that we always have the given lower bound?

Comment: Right, this also assumes the events $A_k$ are disjoint... Yet another serious typo in this book, then.

Comment: @Did Yes, so would this be wrong altogether? I was wondering if it could be modified to give the correct bound, but otherwise I couldn't find any other proofs on this inequality.

Comment: A simple example which destroys the approach is when $A_i=A_1$ for every $i$, then $P_2=\frac12n(n-1)P(A_1)$ and $P_3=\frac16n(n-1)(n-2)P(A_1)$.